# ON LOAD function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please, ther'is this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('divelencoarticoli.html');
});
</script>
```

that loads in the page master.html a sub page called develencoarticoli.html in the body at this div:

```
<div style="width: 100%" id="content">Initial content in test.html</div>
```

My question is: it's possible have a script that load in the DIV #content a page indicated in the div? I don't want call the page from the script, but the script knows the page for include by the div #content.
My target is that with a common script in all the pages of my website, I can load in the body different pages called by the DIV content.

Sorry for my english and for my question, but I am not developer.

Thanks in advance.

---

RESOLVED , thanks to ken.dunnington and epascarello.

Comment: If you can, do you mind re-typing your question?  I can hardly understand what you're saying.

Comment: Are you saying you do not want to hardcode the url "divelencoarticoli.html" into the script? Or are you saying you want to only load a portion of the page "divelencoarticoli.html"?

Comment: Your question is not being answered because it is too difficult to understand what you are asking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to load external content into the `#content` div, without having to explicitly say in the Javascript which URL to use, and be able to use the same code on multiple pages. If so, I'd suggest using `data-*` variables, like so:

```
<div style="width: 100%" id="content" data-content-url="divelencoarticoli.html">Initial content in test.html</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var contentDiv = $("#content");
        var url = contentDiv.data("content-url");
        contentDiv.load(url);
    });
</script>
```

jQuery automatically converts `data-*` attributes into values accessible via the `.data()` method the first time an element is accessed. So you could include the script block above on each of your pages, and just change the data-url in the `#content` div as needed.

Comment: Oops, epascarello beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is a data attribute with the url you want to load

```
<div style="width: 100%" id="content" data-load-url="divelencoarticoli.html">Initial content in test.html</div>
```

Than your JavaScript can just be:

```
$(function() {
    var elem = $("[data-load-url]");
    var url = elem.data("load-url");
    elem.load(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    According to my understanding u want to include the page dynamically by pasing the URL so you do this in this mannner :

<script type="text/javascript">
    function do_the_click(url)
        {
        alert(brl);
        var request  =   $.ajax({
                                 async: false,
                                 url: url, 
                                 contentType: "text/html",
                                 type : "GET",
                                 dataType : "html",                

                    });


                        request.done(function( msg ) {
                          document.getElementById('pass here the ID of div in which the page is included').innerHTML = msg;
                        });

                        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                        });

        }
    </script>

and the HTML boby code should be 
<div id="tagmenu">

            <a href="#" class="button" id="activity" onclick="do_the_click('category/ABB.html');"/>ABB</a>
            <a href="#" class="button" id="javacollections" onclick="do_the_click('category/ABC.html');"/>ABC</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do an ajax call to get the html .  Here is a code that uses jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get( "ajax/divelencoarticoli.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#content" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Much thanks, the problem is resolved. Regards from Italy